# Converting Bootstrap-Material Scss to CSS Using Gulp Gives Import Not Found

Tags: css, npm, sass, gulp

I get the following error after running my gulp task styles:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    static\node_modules\bootstrap-material-design\scss\_variables.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.        
on line 56 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/_variables.scss
        from line 2 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material- design/scss/_core.scss
        from line 3 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material- design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
 ^
```

I have checked that the files are where it's supposed to look. So I am not sure what is wrong. This is my project structure:

```
Project/
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  node_modules/
    bootstrap/
    bootstrap-material-design/
    gulp-sass/
    gulp/
  static/
    node_modules/
        bootstrap/
           scss/
             _functions.scss
        bootstrap-material-design/
           scss/

        gulp-sass/
        gulp/
```

.

```
//gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//style paths
var sassFiles = 'static/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/**/*.scss',
    cssDest = 'static/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/';

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log('GULP GULP GULP')
});

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(sassFiles, ['styles']);
});
```

Partial package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.1.1",
      },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

EDIT

When I hardcoded the path to functions (inside bootstraps _variables.scss), it worked and skipped over to the next import it couldn't find.

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    static\node_modules\bootstrap-material-design\scss\_variables.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/variables.
        on line 57 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material- design/scss/_variables.scss
        from line 2 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material- design/scss/_core.scss
        from line 3 of static/node_modules/bootstrap-material- design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables"; // from bootstrap node_module
  ^
```

variables.scss

```
56: @import "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Git/Project/static/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
```

Grr, this hardcoding doesn't really seem like a solution to me. Not sure why it's not working out of the box. Is the tilde not being recognized or something?

original variables.scss

```
56: @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of `gulp-sass` package not installed yet you can just do `npm install --save-dev gulp-sass` and also make sure to run this command in the folder where `package.json` is there

## UPDATE

**IMPORTANT** you should have only 1 `node_modules` folder which it should be inside your `Project` folder not inside `static` folder.

if you have more than 1 `node_modules` if you run inside `static` it will inject your dependencies there which is not needed for your case.

So please make sure to have only 1 `node_modules` direct into your `Project`

THEN  I would recommend that you uninstall the packages that you installed and install bootstrap and the other packages that you want

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save material-design
```

then your structure will be like that

```
Project/
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  node_modules/
    bootstrap/
    bootstrap-material-design/
    gulp-sass/
    gulp/
  static/
   proejctFiles.scss
```

For sure up to you how to manage your files inside the `static` folder

Then in your `gulpfile.js` you have to edit this path

```
//style paths
var sassFiles = 'static/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/**/*.scss',
    cssDest = 'static/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/';
```

IT should be

```
//style paths
var sassFiles = './static/main.scss',
    cssDest = 'static/dist/css/';
```

inside `main.scss` i import boostrap like that

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

[problem with installing bootstrap-material design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/1105)

as its up there is a problem for installing the bootstrap material design

then everything will be compiled fine like that

[image]

Comment: I have done npm install --save-dev gulp-sass, and it looked like it installed updated package, but it didn't write it into the package.json.
I will try just --save now.

Comment: are you running this command in the same folder where package.json exist ?

Comment: you gave me an idea.I will try installing globally. -edit...same error.

Comment: I would debug it like that first you have to make sure that `gulp-sass` installed in `package.json` in `devDependencies` and make sure also to install it globally maybe it can be the reason if not i will disable all the import files in my scss file and try again if the problem not from the files

Comment: i see now you have wrong structure i will update my post then you can see the point that i saw

Comment: sorry. check again. i forgot to add the node_modules

Comment: I do notice the error says ~bootstrap/scss/functions. but it doesn't include the scss at the end. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.